# Is there any way to disable options while keeping the input functional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I want to disable the options in react select module dynamically, while keeping the input option functional. I tried the code below. But it disables the whole thing. I am trying to disable the options only. I want the module to behave like an input field.

I can conditionally switch between react-select and input field. And that will solve my problem. But is there a way to solve this within react-select?

```
<Select
     value={selectedOptions}
     placeholder={`Start Typing Here...`}
     isDisabled={true}
     onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'name')}
     options={optionList}
/>
```

Comment: can you show what the optionList contain? Because if it's something in the lane of `<option ...>...</option>` you can add `<option disabled>...</option>`.

Comment: You can have the disabled property of each object equals to a boolean property in state and change the state property as required. Maybe this works for your case.

Comment: @Tenzin Kunkyab react select options contains an array of object that has 2 property {value: 0, label: 'Label1'}. it's not like normal select tag

Comment: @shubham-gupta i don't want the whole Select to be disabled. I just want that the options wont appear.

Comment: @RakibUddin can you share a jsfiddle/codesandbox? So that it'd be easier for anyone to help.

Comment: @RakibUddin could you clarify the purpose ? Do you want the dropdown to open of not ? Do you want to see the options but disabled or no options at all ? Do you have some design example you could share for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: @Laura I don't want the drop-down to open while the input is functional. I am sorry but i can not share the code. I am working on a project and its confidential.

Answer (score 0):

[image] 
Thanks everyone for reaching out. I did make a custom react-select that satisfies my needs. I wish react select had that option. But i think it's not possible because react-select takes the value from the drop-down. And the input works as a search filter.